# DynamoDB write is too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I use Lambda to read from a JSON Api and write in DynamoDB via http request. The JSON Api is very big (has 200k objects) and my function is extremely slow with writing to DynamoDB. I used the regular write function and after 10 min I could only populate 5k rows in my DynamoDB table. I was thinking about using BatchWriteItem but since it can only do 25 puts in one batch, it would still take too much time to write all 200k rows. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be because you're being throttled.

**For Lambda**

There are a maximum number of concurrent invocations of Lambdas that can be running at a time, the [default limit is 1000 concurrent requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html).

If you have more than 1000 concurrent requests at the same time you will need to reach out to AWS Support to increase this, you will also need to provide a business use case for why it needs to support this.

**For DynamoDB**

Whether you use batch or single `PutItem` your DynamoDB table is configured with a number of [WCU (Write Credit Units) and RCU (Read Credit Units)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html).

A single write credit unit covers 1 write of an item 1Kb or less (every extra kb is another unit). If you exceed this you will start to be throttled for write requests, if you're using the SDK it may use exponential backoff as well to keep attempting to write.

As a solution for this you should do one of the following:

- If this is a one time process you can adjust the WCU as a fixed number, then wait 5 minutes for it to increase and then scale down.
- If this is a natural flow on your app then enable DynamoDB autoscaling to naturally increase and decrease throughout the day

In addition look at your data modelling as this can lead to throttling too.

> In extreme cases, throttling can occur if a single partition receives more than 3,000 RCUs or 1,000 WCUs

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, it is very helpful! 
The write operation is used on a daily basis so I followed your second solution and enabled auto scaling with a capacity set to 70% target utilization. Can I ask you another question concerning the primary key? I used Date.now() to generate the id for each item but that will cause collisions since the write operation works so fast. What can I use as a primary key instead? There is no id in the datatset unfortunately.

Comment: Sure, how do you normally retrieve the data? You can always concatenate multiple fields to form a primary key but t really depends on how you'd retrieve it

Comment: The dataset looks a little something like this: date, bike model, production time in min. 

I retrieve the data by date since I want to calculate the average production time for each day and put it in a second table. Since the same bike model is produced multiple times per day, concatenating the two fields still won't give me a unique key.

Comment: Personally I'd have chosen Bike Model as the partition key, then had a sort key of a date time. Otherwise it'll be hard to make this unique :(

Comment: That's true, a timestamp would be helpful in this case. Unfortunately I only have the date. Is there still a way to make it work?

Comment: You'd need to generate a UUID I think